# Copy any k folders from a given directory to a destination

Tags: linux, copy-paste, deep-copy

I have a directory that has thousands of folders which might have subfolders nested in it. How to copy any `k` folders along with nesting files/folders to a destination directory.

`cp -r source_dir dest_dir` --- is to expensive for me.

Doing on Linux based machine?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean with "copy any `k` folders along with nesting files/folders". Do you want to somehow count the immediate subdirectories of `source_dir`? If you have e.g. `source_dir/foo` and `source_dir/bar` etc. , do you want to get `dest_dir/foo` etc. or `dest_dir/source_dir/foo` etc.? Does `dest_dir` already exist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correct. See my comment.

This script assumes you only want to count immediate subdirectories of `source_dir`. It ignores files located directly in `source_dir` (using `find`'s `type -f`) With `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` only the immediate subdirectories are printed, not `source_dir` itself.

```
mkdir -p dest_dir
find source_dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | tail +"$START" | head -"$COUNT" | xargs cp -r -t dest_dir/.
```

`$START` is the number of the first directory to be copied (`1`...`n`), `$COUNT` the number of directories (`k`).

If some other process add/removes/changes subdirectories of `source_dir`, the output of `find` will change, so the result of subsequent executions of the command might not match.